Identify this film where a school girl's personal diary got so much attention
I remember a color film  may be of 90's or more, where The main lead is a girl who writes every movement of her life in a diary but with little divergence. I mean she writes in the diary.. all the reactions she wants to do in a moment but she doesn't or is unable to do them.
Somehow her diary gets published and she gets so much attention. But in the end it turns out bad for her when during a TV interview she mistakenly tolls that the stories in the diary are real and is of her school and that, every character in the diary belongs to the school students. And most of the schoolmates end up hating her for portraying them in a wrong way.  

Seems, the movie plot you have described here is of 2006 TV movie Read it and Weep
IMDB Synopsis

A young girl turns into an A-List celebrity over night when her
  private journal is accidently published and becomes a best-seller.

Brief description of the movie plot from Wiki

As an English assignment, she has to write an essay of her choice. Her
  printer dies and Lenny refuses to let her use his. Lindsay offers to
  print the essay if Jamie emails it to her, but she accidentally sends
  her the journal. After Lindsay turns the journal in for the English
  assignment, it wins a writing contest. Jamie's book attracts a lot of
  publicity and eventually becomes a bestseller. She appears at many
  book signings, reality TV shows and is often interviewed. Soon,
  success gets the better of Jamie; she becomes increasingly
  materialistic and critical of the world around her, quitting her job
  at her father's pizza place, ridiculing her brother's guitar playing,
  and favoring fame over her friends. Her newfound popularity is dashed
  when she reveals on a television interview that the antagonist of her
  novel is based on Sawyer.

